# Laravel: Cannot get working Notification::assertSentTo when testing command

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

**Laravel 9**

My Laravel application does have previous tests that validate notifications send. The typical

```php
Notification::fake();

$this->post('/forgot-password', ['email' => $user->email]);

Notification::assertSentTo($user, ResetPassword::class);
```

and some various similar others. But... now that I'm testing notifications that are sent from a command call, things happen differently.

```
public function testHandle_happyPath()
{
    Notification::fake();

    $customer = CustomerFactory::new()->default()->create([
        'account_status' => AccountStatus::TRIAL,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->subDays(28)
    ]);
    ConfigurationKey::PREVIOUS_DAYS_TO_NOTIFY_TRIAL_EXPIRY()->setInteger(2);

    $result = $this->artisan(NotifyTrialsToExpireCommand::class);

    $customer->refresh();
    $result->assertSuccessful();
    Notification::assertSentTo($customer, TrialNextToExpireNotification::class);
}
```

The result is

> The expected [App\Notifications\TrialNextToExpireNotification] notification was not sent.

My phpunit conf already haves `<server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>` to avoid any related issue.

I've tested it manually and it works.

It's clear that it relates directly to the use of `$this->artisan` call. What thing could I ignore? This type of tests should be prepared differently? I'ts not possible to test this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running it this way and see what happens. Instead of

```php
$result = $this->artisan(NotifyTrialsToExpireCommand::class);

$customer->refresh();
$result->assertSuccessful();
```

Run:

```php
$this->artisan(NotifyTrialsToExpireCommand::class)
    ->assertSuccessful();

$customer->refresh();
```

Yes, changing the order like that (using a variable) affects when it is run.

Based on how `$this->artisan(...)` works, it will use the `__destruct` (read more [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/3141ef2056213854abb62e2f6f4127525c3fc050/src/Illuminate/Testing/PendingCommand.php#L473-L485) about Laravel; [official PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor) about it) magic PHP keyword to execute the command, and because you are using `$result =`  and then calling the assert, it may not trigger correctly (as expected).

Comment: In fact... It changed it all! And it works. .. why? I cannot see any important action performed by assertSuccessful() alongside validate exit code.   -  Thxs !

Comment: Check the first documentation I shared (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/3141ef2056213854abb62e2f6f4127525c3fc050/src/Illuminate/Testing/PendingCommand.php#L473-L485), what it does is, when PHP detects that nothing else is calling/using the resulting object that `$this->artisan()` generates (`PendingCommand` class), it will then run the command, your issue was that the command was not run until after the `$resul->assertSuccessful()`, so your `$customer->refresh` before that line is still unchanged